# Перемещение объекта между двумя точками привязанного к мыши

Tags: геометрия, three.js

- на плоскости лежат две точки, они друг с другом соединены(отрезок).
- есть курсор мыши, к которому прикреплён mesh.
- у курсора есть радиус.
- когда курсор с mesh пересекают отрезок между точками, mesh прилипает к отрезку и двигается только вдоль данного отрезка.
- когда радиус мыши выходит за пределы отрезка, mesh продолжает следовать за мышью.

Вопрос - как это возможно реализовать и через что?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно начать отсюда: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Line3.closestPointToPoint

Comment: Как обычно - разделить на подзадачи и решать их

Comment: в общем, всё оказалось гораздо проще, легче было сделать выставление перпендикуляра.
Было найдено пересечение курсора мыши(перпендикуляр) с отрезком, после чего нашёл точку и всё заработало :)